# ImageSharp get dominant color from a stream

Tags: c#, imagesharp

I'm trying to find an alternative to `System.Drawing` and `ColorThief` to be used in a docker container with Linux (because the prior mentioned have some issues).

So far I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JimBobSquarePants/12e0ef5d904d03110febea196cf1d6ee)

But it seems to be on an older version since `OctreeQuantizer` had now a different constructor.

I've tried different approaches but most of the times I either always get `FFFFFF` or a null reference exception.

I get the NRE when I try `new OctreeQuantizer(new QuantizerOptions { Dither = null, MaxColors = 1 })` which I thought might be the same as in the gist. I get always white when I play around with the QuantizerOptions.

I have little to no experience in image processing and ImageSharp, feels like I'm missing something.

tl;dr: trying to find the dominant color from a stream using ImageSharp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved using the code below. It is a bit hacky but works well for me.

```
using var image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(imageBytes);

image.Mutate(x => x
    .Resize(new ResizeOptions {Sampler = KnownResamplers.NearestNeighbor, Size = new Size(100, 0)}));

int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;
int totalPixels = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        var pixel = image[x, y];

        r += Convert.ToInt32(pixel.R);
        g += Convert.ToInt32(pixel.G);
        b += Convert.ToInt32(pixel.B);

        totalPixels++;
    }
}

r /= totalPixels;
g /= totalPixels;
b /= totalPixels;

Rgba32 dominantColor = new Rgba32((byte) r, (byte) g, (byte) b, 255);

// This will give you a dominant color in HEX format i.e #5E35B1FF
string hexColor = dominant.ToHex();
```